# How can this vector component be negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Problem

> Let vector **A** $ = \langle a, 2\rangle$ and vector **B** $ = \langle 1, 3\rangle$. For what values of $a$ is the component of **A** along **B**
>   negative?

Computationally, I know how to get the answer, but intuitively, the component of **A** along **B** being negative doesn't make sense to me. If **B** was along either the x-axis or y-axis, then the component of **A** being negative would make sense but **B** is not along any particular axis. **B** is just pointing in some random direction, so how can the length of the projection of **A** onto this random direction be given a sign?

Comment: What does "A along B" mean? I think this means "Which values of $a$ make the angle between A and B larger than 90 degrees, but I am not sure

Comment: The component along the $x$ axis is not a number, but rather a scalar multiple of the vector $(1,0)$; the component is negative when the scalar is negative, and positive when the scalar is positive. Similarly, the component of $\mathbf{A}$ along $\mathbf{B}$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{B}$; it is positive if this scalar is positive, and it is negative if the scalar is negative.

Comment: @David probably the inner product $\langle A,B \rangle$ (perhaps with some normalization) and maybe multiplied by the unit vector of $B$

Comment: Every vector has a direction. The component of $-B$ along $B$ is negative, for example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  So you're saying basically that if the component of **A** is pointing in the opposite direction of the vector **B** then the component is negative.

Comment: The $x$- and $y$-axes are also “random” directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question with what I think is the usual, standard meaning of things, the component of $\;A\;$ along $\;B\;$ is just the length of the orthogonal projection of $\;A\;$ on the subspace $\;Span\{B\}\;$, so:

$$\text{comp}_B\,(A):=\frac{A\bullet B}{\left\|B\right\|}=\frac{(a,2)\bullet (1,3)}{\left\|(1,3)\right\|}=\frac{a+6}{\sqrt{10}}$$

End the argument now.